# Why require build tool 29.0.2 when 29.0.3 is present?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-sdk-tools

I created a flutter app. I run it and it builds fine and it runs.

Now I change the project structure to android in order to build signed apk. Gradle updates and now it says can't find build tool 29.0.2. I checked and found that 29.0.3 is installed. Why do we need different tools for the same platform? And for the same program?

Comment: Your app is using build Tools Version 29.0.2. Modify buildToolsVersion to 29.0.3 in your apps build.gradle file and re sync the project.

Comment: I ended up downloading 29.0.2. But why does gradle download so many files? Now that I am building apk, it does build but while building it downloads kotlin compilers and what nots. Why gradle why?

Answer (score 3):

Since it is asking for build tool 29.0.2 when 29.0.3 present(you don't need to download 29.0.2 again), you can go to the project's `build.gradle` file in the 'app' module. Open the file and you can either add or update the Builds Tools version you want to use by either updating/adding the property in the android section:

```
android {
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"
    ....
}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It'll keep using 29.0.2, despite changing the file to 29.0.3

Answer (score 3):

I have met the same issue with you. And I finally find that we should set every module `buildToolsVersion "29.0.3"`. And then It can build.
And the reason I guess, it is that if you don't set buildToolsVersion, gradle will set a default buildToolsVersion